# Python MySQL database, data update error?

Tags: python, mysql

In the Python software language, the str variant gives an error when adding to the MySQL database. To me, this is the problem of **character.** Could you help?

The lines of code I wrote are at the bottom.

```
rezerve='Aşkım Nasılsın?'
new_status = telStatus + 1
try:
    tablo_birak = "UPDATE denemetablodd SET status='%s', rezerve='%s' WHERE ıd=1" % (str(new_status), str(rezerve))
    imlec.execute(tablo_birak)
    mysqlBaglanti.commit()
except:
    mysqlBaglanti.rollback()
```

Comment: Can you post in your question the exact error which python is outputting?

Comment: You should use a prepared statement instead of substituting into the string.

Comment: @JoshKopen ,
This is the mistake I get .  UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are not using values which are on an ascii chart. Many programs only use symbols which are in the first 128 ascii values (http://www.asciitable.com/index/asciifull.gif). Characters such as the S with the line below it are not accepted by these programs. Although I understand these may be a part of this language, my best advice would be to change these to the closest english alphabet approximation otherwise you will not be able to use this version of mySQL. Perhaps make the value of $rezerve into "Askim Nasilsin?" if you want to be able to use mySQL.

Comment: I have to use this text in its original form. Do I have a chance to make it compatible with Ascii? for example;  rezerve.encode('utf-8')

Comment: That would work. You just need to make sure all answers are ASCII. Don't forget when you are reading back out to then decode them.